# Why Varnish does not work with nginx ssl?

Tags: nginx, varnish, nginx-config

I have a server on Ubuntu 20.04.6 using Nginx with ssl and Varnish 6.2.1. I'm getting the error:
`400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)`

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/file:

```
server {
    listen 91 ssl http2;
    server_name my_site_name;
    # varnish proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_site_name/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_site_name/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

My /etc/varnish/default.vcl:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "my_https_site";
    .port = "85";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (client.ip != "127.0.0.1" && req.http.host ~ "my_host.by") {
       set req.http.x-redir = "https://my_https_site" + req.url;
       return(synth(850, ""));
    }
}
sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.status == 850) {
       set resp.http.Location = req.http.x-redir;
       set resp.status = 301;
       return (deliver);
    }
}
```

My /etc/default/varnish:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

As I see the result from command varnishstat works fine, receive the data.

Varnish log (backend "varnishlog -b"):

```
*   << BeReq    >> 98394     
-   Begin          bereq 98393 fetch
-   VCL_use        boot
-   Timestamp      Start: 1682520086.557505 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    Host: my_host
-   BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
-   BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
-   BereqHeader    upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   BereqHeader    accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
-   BereqHeader    sec-fetch-site: none
-   BereqHeader    sec-fetch-mode: navigate
-   BereqHeader    sec-fetch-user: ?1
-   BereqHeader    sec-fetch-dest: document
-   BereqHeader    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 98394
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   BackendOpen    26 default 181.122.19.2 85 181.122.19.2 33736
-   BackendStart   181.122.19.2 85
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1682520086.557843 0.000338 0.000338
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1682520086.558193 0.000688 0.000350
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   400
-   BerespReason   Bad Request
-   BerespHeader   Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
-   BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 26 Apr 2023 14:41:26 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html
-   BerespHeader   Content-Length: 666
-   BerespHeader   Connection: close
-   TTL            RFC -1 10 0 1682520087 1682520087 1682520086 0 0 cacheable
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
-   TTL            VCL 120 10 0 1682520087 cacheable
-   TTL            VCL 120 10 0 1682520087 uncacheable
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Filters        
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   Fetch_Body     3 length stream
-   BackendClose   26 default
-   Timestamp      BerespBody: 1682520086.558474 0.000969 0.000281
-   Length         666
-   BereqAcct      657 0 657 161 666 827
-   End
```

Client log:

```
*   << Request  >> 98399     
-   Begin          req 98398 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1682521060.864589 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1682521060.864589 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 35458 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /favicon.ico
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Connection: upgrade
-   ReqHeader      Host: my_host
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   ReqHeader      user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
-   ReqHeader      accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-site: same-origin
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-dest: image
-   ReqHeader      referer: https://alva.by:91/
-   ReqHeader      accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     hash
-   ReqUnset       accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 98400 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1682521060.865292 0.000702 0.000702
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     400
-   RespReason     Bad Request
-   RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 26 Apr 2023 14:57:40 GMT
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 666
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 98399
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1682521060.865304 0.000715 0.000012
-   Filters        
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1682521060.865364 0.000775 0.000061
-   ReqAcct        568 0 568 224 666 890
-   End
```

I tried lots of things such as changing default.vcl file, changing sites-available's file and so on.

P.S. Ports are opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It's because I use NOT Varnish Enterprise, it's not free. But, I realize how to work with that on my PC with nginx. So there is some notes (maybe it'll help someone).

How do requests work with nginx?

1. You send request to your remote (or local) server with a defined port (for example 80) via a web browser -> "https://myServer:80"
2. Then nginx sends it to varnsih on 6081 port (by default)
3. Varnish does its logic and sends it forward to your backend localhost
4. Then it goes on reverse path.

So, if you worked with your site you wouldn't use other remote origins for cashing, right?

So, in /etc/varnish/default.vcl use http protocol.

P.S. Now I'm researching how I can use varnish with docker, bcz docker use its own network.

Hope, that will help someone